# how to detect image redirect in js

Tags: javascript, html

right now the jsp code will create html like below

```
<a href="xxxxxx">
 <img width="143" height="143" src="http://yyyyyyyy.jpg">
</a>
```

while loading the page the yyyyyyyy.jpg will be redirect to xxxxx.jpg

Since the yyyyyyyy.jpg is provided by other service provider i dont know whether one image will be redirect or not .

My question is : is there any way i can do  in  js , to detect a image redirected or not  or can i test all url in  when document ready to know whether one image url will be redirected.

Thanks

Comment: I asked a similar question several months ago and found no way to detect what the redirected URL was, even if on the same domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the URL does not have matching domain, protocol and port, then you **can't** see if it redirects (because of [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)) with JavaScript only, unless it explicitly allows you to via [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing).

You could use a server side language to detect it.

Comment: Hi alex thanks for the reply , i got the yyyyyyyy.jpg which is a full image url from our side server which parse the return xml from a third server provider. I really have no idea why they give a image url but redirect that to another one. Maybe the url they provide do have image then jump to an error image.